# x (> if bool else <) y

Tags: python, function, boolean-logic

I'm looking for a logic to use a function with different operators.

Is there a way to implement the logic to use a boolean to determine the operator in the comparison? something along the lines of

```
while df["column"][i + period] (> if bool_var else <=) min(df["column"])
```

Edit: can anyone explicitly show me how that logic would be implemented with the operator module?

```
while operator.gt(a, b) if bool_var else operator.eq(a, b): ?
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there. Please provide a _minimal_ example to illustrate your needs. I'm guessing that you might want something like the functions provided by the `operator` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicated blocks in your `if/else` branching all you need is to change your `while` statement basing on `positive` flag and comparison operator created by [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module:

```
from operator import eq, gt

def check_trends(df, set_lenght, positive=True, get_index=False):
    periods = []
    op = gt if positive else eq  # select operator
    
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        period = 0
        while op(df["perc_btc"][i + period], min(df["perc_btc"])):
            if len(df.index) <= (i + period + 1):
                break
            period += 1
        if period > set_lenght:
            periods.append([i, period])
            if get_index:
                return [i, i + period]  # returns the last starting point
    return periods
```

Comment: thank you very much. solved the problem

Comment: @PetersServers, you're welcome. Actually, your initial question description with extended code seemed clear for me (I would not delete that function from description).

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to make two separate comparisons, each *contingent on* `newbool`. In this example `a` is `df["column"][i + period]` and `b` is  `min(df["column"]`.

```
>>> newbool = True
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 5
>>> (a>b and newbool) or (a<=b and not newbool)
False
>>> newbool = False
>>> (a>b and newbool) or (a<=b and not newbool)
True
>>> a = 6
>>> (a>b and newbool) or (a<=b and not newbool)
False
>>> newbool = True
>>> (a>b and newbool) or (a<=b and not newbool)
True
>>>
```

---

```
df["column"][i + period]
```

Can probably be written as

```
df.loc[i+period,"column"]
```

If it can it should be. [Different choices for indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

---

To prevent a very long while statement the terms could be assigned to names before and at the bottom of the loop.

```
a = df.loc[i+period,"column"]>min(df["column"]
b = min(df["column"]
while (a>b and newbool) or (a<=b and not newbool)):
    # all the other stuff
    ...
    a = df.loc[i+period,"column"]
    b = min(df["column"])
```